# How to define a specific function for saving and retrieving varchar fields in/from DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

We have an old DB that we cannot change due to compatibility issues. So most of the varchar fields contain non unicode characters that are read through a charset, cp1251 to be exact.

We are developing new application on the old DB, using EF4.1. Having the data in ascii cp1251 and having to display it in utf-8 is the problem. Unfortunately, I'm new to the EF. So I'm having trouble all over the place.

I'm looking for a way to implement 2 functions that convert the string from cp1251 to utf-8 right at the data retrieval and input from/to DB.

Let me put it this way, have some way to catch the EF attempt to save a varchar field take its current data and convert into cp1251 format and vice versa when retrieving regardless of the field, table, or db currently being used, it would be more of a connection specific implementation.

We don't have a Data Access Layer nor Business Logic, we just go straight from UI to EF4.1, and any Business Logic needing implementation we just put them DbContext class.

I just don't know what to look for online, or where to begin.

any pointers welcome. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that all fields which are using cp1251 are marked as non unicode and try to use it. IMHO it should work. There is no extension point to add custom conversion function for some data type.

To make property non-unicode in EDMX simply set it in property pages of the property. To make it non-unicode in code mapping use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>()
            .Property(p => p.YourStringProperty)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: Can substitute all string properties with a ComplexType that does the conversion? I think complex types had a bug somewhere regarding stored procedures or something, in EF4.1?